# How to resize ubuntu partition

Tags: dual-boot, gparted, partitioning

I have got 3 partitions.

- partition on /dev/sda1 is for files.
- partition on /dev/sda2 is for microsoft windows (in this partition i have got unallocated space).
- partition on /dev/sda3 is extended partition (/dev/sda4 and 5 is for ubuntu).

I want to resize Ubuntu partition with only 20 gb.
I tried make it bigger but I can only make it smaller.

Comment: What do you mean you have "unallocated space" in your windows partition? Unallocated space will have no partition associated.

Comment: Zeroth, BACKUP! First, boot Windows and run the disk defragmentation/cleanup tool. Note (write this down!) how much space is actually used. Shutdown Windows politely, so it has a chance to save to disk. Boot Windows again. Happy? Shutdown Windows politely. Boot Gparted from Live CD/USB. Shrink `/dev/sda2` to slightly larger than  recorded space, by moving the upper edge down.  Expand `/dev/sda3` into the space. Then expand/mode `/dev/sda4` and `/dev/sda5`. YMMV.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the output of `sudo parted -l /dev/sda` and/or a screenshot of GParted.

Answer (score 0):

You have to have unallocated space following the partition to make it larger.  If you want to take space from the earlier partition, you have to first shrink it, then move the later partitions to the left, and 
*then* you can make them larger.